# ThreeJS- Ensuring objects placed on sphere are resting on the surface

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, three.js, gis

I have a globe with the data of country borders.

I have spheres placed at the center of the bounding box of each country- unfortunately for large countries such as the US, Russia and China or countries like France with islands in the atlantic, the center of the bounding box does not accurately reflect the location of the country.

Is there any way of ensuring the spheres are correctly positioned? I am happy to go in and manually move the problem cases, but if there is a general fix I'd appreciate that too.

The JSON file I'm getting my data from looks like this:

```
{'type': 'MultiPolygon',
     'arcs': [[[1302]],
      [[-374,
        -1025,
        1303,
        -873,
        1304,
        -411,
        1305,
        -409,
        1306,
        1307,
        -928,
        -1283]],
      [[1308]],
      [[1309]],
      [[1310]],
      [[1311]],
      [[1312]],
      [[1313]],
      [[1314]],
      [[-386, 1315, 1316]]],
     'id': '250',
     'properties': {'name': 'France', 'Press Freedom Index': 17.89}}
```

(name and press freedom are stats I added myself) As you can see, The separate regions are held in separate list. How can I make use of this information to position my spheres in the correct location?

Here is a snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div id='container'></div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson-client@3"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-array@1"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-collection@1"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-dispatch@1"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-request@1"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-timer@1"></script>
<script type='module'>
import * as THREE from "https://unpkg.com/three@0.127.0/build/three.module.js";
import {OrbitControls} from "https://unpkg.com/three@0.127.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";

var width = 750;
  var height = 750;
  var radius = 168,
  mesh,
  graticule,
  scene = new THREE.Scene(),
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, width / height, 1, 1000),
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true}),
  container = document.getElementById( 'container' ),
  controls;

  scene.background = new THREE.Color( "rgb(20,20,20)" )

  camera.position.z = 320;
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(width, height);
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  let earthPivot = new THREE.Group();

  d3.json("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/world-atlas@2/countries-50m.json", function(error, topology) {
    if (error) throw error;
    var countries = []
    var cones = []
    for (var i = 0; i < topology.objects.countries.geometries.length; i++) {
      var rgb = [];
      var newcolor;
      for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        rgb.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255));
        newcolor = 'rgb('+ rgb.join(',') +')';
      }
      var mesh = wireframe(topojson.mesh(topology, topology.objects.countries.geometries[i]), new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color:newcolor, linewidth: 5}))
      countries.push(mesh);
      scene.add(mesh);

      mesh.geometry.computeBoundingBox()
      var center = new THREE.Vector3();
      mesh.geometry.boundingBox.getCenter(center)

          mesh.add( earthPivot );
      let height = 5;
      // height = height ? height : 0;
      const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( height, 50, 36);
      const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: newcolor} );
      const cone = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
      cone.position.x = center.x;
      cone.position.y = center.y;
      cone.position.z = center.z;
      cones.push(cone);
      earthPivot.add( cone );
    }
    
    controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    d3.timer(function(t) {
        for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
          countries[i].rotation.x = Math.sin(t / 21000) * Math.PI / 3 - Math.PI / 2;
          countries[i].rotation.z = t / 20000;
          cones[i].rotation.x = Math.sin(t / 21000) * Math.PI / 3 - Math.PI / 2;
          cones[i].rotation.z = t / 20000;
        }

      renderer.render(scene, camera)
    });
  });

  // Converts a point [longitude, latitude] in degrees to a THREE.Vector3.
  function vertex(point) {
    var lambda = point[0] * Math.PI / 180,
    phi = point[1] * Math.PI / 180,
    cosPhi = Math.cos(phi);
    return new THREE.Vector3(
      radius * cosPhi * Math.cos(lambda),
      radius * cosPhi * Math.sin(lambda),
      radius * Math.sin(phi)
    );
  }

  // Converts a GeoJSON MultiLineString in spherical coordinates to a THREE.LineSegments.
  function wireframe(multilinestring, material) {
    var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry;
    var pointsArray = new Array();
    multilinestring.coordinates.forEach(function(line) {
      d3.pairs(line.map(vertex), function(a, b) {
        pointsArray.push(a,b);
      });
    });
    geometry.setFromPoints(pointsArray);
    return new THREE.LineSegments(geometry, material);
  }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: When you set position of a sphere (x, y, z separately), you can do it one line `cone.position.copy(center);`, and then set position's length this way `cone.position.setLength(radius + height);`.

Comment: @prisoner849 Thank you! Very helpful.